# AsyncTask onDraw method with time delay

Tags: android, android-asynctask, ondraw

I want to make an activity where user at the beginning will see  first statement then after 2 sec, there'll be second statement and at last there show up timer with progress drawn on canvas in onDraw method.

Timer should only last 5 seconds, but when I add those two 2 sec breaks, user will see only last second (5-2-2). I tried to change code where progress is calculated, but I just make things worse.

I cutted out variable declaration and all content about shapes being drawing. Maybe i should declarate in diffrent moment startTime and currentTime.

```
public class CircleTimer extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       final CircularCountdown view  = new CircularCountdown(this);
        setContentView(view);

        AsyncTask<Void, Boolean, Void> task = new AsyncTask<Void, Boolean, Void>() {

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                    publishProgress(true);
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
                return null;
            }

            protected void onProgressUpdate(Boolean... progress) {
                view.setSecondDrawStep(progress[0]);
                view.invalidate();
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                view.setThirdDrawStep(true);
                view.invalidate();
            }
        };
        task.execute((Void[])null);
    }

    private class CircularCountdown extends View {


        public CircularCountdown(Context context) {
            super(context);


            maxTime = 5000;

            startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            currentTime = startTime;

            viewHandler = new Handler();
            updateView = new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run(){
                    currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    progressMillisecond = Math.abs(startTime - currentTime) % maxTime;
                    progress = (double) (progressMillisecond) / maxTime;
                    CircularCountdown.this.invalidate();
                    viewHandler.postDelayed(updateView, 1000/60);
                }
            };
            viewHandler.post(updateView);
        }

        boolean secondDrawStep = false;
        boolean thirdDrawStep = false;

        public void setSecondDrawStep(boolean flag) {
            secondDrawStep = flag;
        }

        public void setThirdDrawStep(boolean flag) {
            thirdDrawStep = flag;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            super.onDraw(canvas);

            canvas.drawText("FIRST statement",
                    centerWidthCenter,
                    centerHeightCenter + textOffset,
                    nameTextPaint);

            if (secondDrawStep) {
                canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);

                canvas.drawText("SECOND statement",
                        centerWidthCenter,
                        centerHeightCenter + textOffset,
                        nameTextPaint);
            }

            if (thirdDrawStep) {
                canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);

                canvas.drawArc(circleBounds, -90, (float) (progress * 360), false, progressPaint);

                canvas.drawText((int) Math.abs(5 - (progressMillisecond / 1000)) + "s",
                        centerWidth,
                        centerHeight + textOffset,
                        textPaint);
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you please fix your formatting? Source code comments in SO should be indented with four spaces.

Comment: I fixed it. Just deleted unnecessary comment.